# How to plot only max values using python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to make a graph about how the maximum value of a cluster of points at any given x coordinate changes over time.

### What I have achieved so far:

[image: what i achieved so far]

### What I want to achieve:

[image: what i want to achieve, removing the circled point, i know how to do the line plot]

I was thinking that making a subset of the data with only the day and value, and then getting the maximum value of the array either by iterating trough it or using a function. But I don't know if it's possible like here:

[image: like here]

Here's my code

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('strong.csv', names=[
                  'time', 'exercise', 'set_number', 'mass', 'reps'],parse_dates=['time'])
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time,format='%Y-%m-%d')

df_exercise = df[(df.exercise == 'Bench Press (Barbell)')]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(
    df_exercise.time,df_exercise.mass, c='Orange', s=30
)
ax.set(xlabel='Day', ylabel='Weight [ kg ]',
       title='Time/Weight')
plt.xticks(fontsize=8,rotation=45)       
plt.show()
plt.savefig('grafic.png')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group the dataframe by date and aggregate the maxima:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': np.repeat(pd.date_range('2021-03-01', periods=6), 2),
                   'mass': np.random.randint(20, 56, 12),
                   'excersie': 'Bench Press (Barbell)'})
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df_exercise = df  # just creating a dataframe similar to the question's

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 5))
ax1.scatter(df_exercise.time, df_exercise.mass, c='limegreen', s=30)

df_plot = df_exercise.groupby('time')['mass'].agg('max')
ax2.scatter(df_exercise.time, df_exercise.mass, c='limegreen', s=30, alpha=0.3)
ax2.scatter(df_plot.index, df_plot.values, c='orange', s=30)
ax2.plot(df_plot.index, df_plot.values, c='black', lw=2, zorder=0)

for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    ax.set(xlabel='Day', ylabel='Weight [ kg ]', title='Time/Weight')
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=8, labelrotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: groupby date, aggregate max]